# Why doesn't the date/time come through correctly with PHP/MSSQL?

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

I recently upgraded the running version of PHP on my server to 5.3.20. Since then, whenever I pull datetimes out of a MSSQL database (mssql_query) I get weirdly wrong dates coming through.

I have checked the locale settings and the default timezone is set to 'Australia/Brisbane', I've also checked the php.ini settings and confirmed that the `mssql.datetimeconvert` is turned off. The dates seem to come through preformatted (without seconds) when the option is turned on, however when the option is turned off I get a date that looks like this.

> mssql.datetimeconvert (off): 2013-07-**38** 16:00:20
>
> mssql.datetimeconvert (on): Feb 07 2013 09:37PM

Is there a simple fix?

Here is the code that compares output between mysql/mssql sources:

```
$rs = $db->query("select id, servertime from bobstable where id = 86427420");
$mss_set = mssql_query("select id, servertime from T_bobstable WITH (NOLOCK) where id = 86427420");

$myrow = $rs->fetch_assoc();
$msrow = mssql_fetch_array($mss_set);

var_dump($myrow);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($msrow);
```

which outputs as follows:

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(8) "86427420" ["servertime"]=> string(19) "2013-02-08 14:00:24" } 
array(4) { [0]=> float(86427420) ["id"]=> float(86427420) [1]=> string(19) "2013-08-39 24:673:0" ["servertime"]=> string(19) "2013-08-39 24:673:0" }
```

and this is the output that I receive right out of SQL Server Studio

```
2013-02-08 14:00:24.673
```

I can understand how it's been formatted (as that part of the problem was answered below) but I can't understand why it's coming through in this format or how to change PHP's configuration to avoid this. Before I upgraded PHP it used to come through as **2013-02-08 14:00:24**. Has anyone experienced or seen this happen before?

Comment: Don't know the answer, but out of interest do you get this with PDO also? Is the clock set correctly on the database server? Do queries made locally to the SQL Server console render dates correctly?

Comment: Is `mssql.datetimecovert` a typo here, or did you get it wrong in your php.ini? It's missing an 'n'.

Comment: @halfer, just a typo - its actually spelt correctly in the ini file.

Comment: @halfer. Database server returns values through SQL Studio correctly with the same query.

Comment: I've corrected that for you. Note you can edit your question at any time if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that seems to stick:-

I downgraded the FreeTDS version that was installed on the server from:

```
freetds.x86_64 0.91-2.el5  to 
freetds.x86_64 0.64-11.el5.centos
```

And that fixed the dates.

Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

today the 07 february the DAYOFYEAR() is 38.

probably the probleme is on the date format